# Next.js dynamic routes not working on production (after page refresh)

Tags: firebase, next.js, routes, server-side-rendering

I can't seem to get dynamic routes in Next.js working with Firebase hosting. Everything works fine locally using the emulators, but after deploying the application using `firebase deploy` the dynamic route is not directly accessible. Instead, I just get redirected to the homepage.

I have carefully read the documententation and walked through the steps as described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs.

**Steps to reproduce**

In this application, users are able to create and join rooms. Each room is a unique entry in a Firebase collection and can be accessed via `/rooms/{roomId}`. As stated before, everything works well locally. The issue comes after deploying the application (SSR function). I am able to create a room and view the room page after the application redirects me using [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush). However, if I refresh the page or I open up another tab and browse to the URL directly, I see the homepage instead.

It is hard to see as the recording stops right when the page is refreshed. But on the last frame I have joined the room (i.e. `/room/IRLdCgdaOOTrIJunCDuv/`. If I then refresh the page, the text "Home" (on the first frame) is shown:

[image: chrome-capture-2022-9-26]

**Project setup**

My `firebase.json` looks as follows:

```json
{
  "firestore": { ... },
  "functions": [ ... ],
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    // I've also  tried using `cleanUrls` and `trailingSlash` but with no luck
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": { ... },
  "database": { ... },
  "emulators": { ... },
  "extensions": { ... }
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Relevant dependencies in `package.json`:

```json
{
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
```

Hoping someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue by running `firebase deploy` in debug mode. The issue was in the resulting`firebase.json`:

[image]

After removing the `rewrites` attribute in `firebase.json` the issue was resolved. All requests go pass the ssr function now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

But in the `firebase,json` file I didn't have a `rewrites`, And i could not find where i could edit the `firebase.json` on the serverside.

I also did a `firebase deploy –-debug`
And saw that

```
 "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": {
            "functionId": "ssrrsponse366109"
          }
        }
      ],
```

was added.
I checked that function and saw the folling error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'firebase' imported from /workspace/.next/server/pages/_app.js at new NodeError 
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

I downloaded the source, and checked the `package.json` and it was missing  firebase dependency

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "firebase-frameworks": "^0.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.23.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  }
}
```

Did `npm i firebase` , zipped up the folder again exculding the newly created node_modules folder.
Edited the function ,uploaded the new zip, deployed the function.

The error was gone.
Site worked an could refresh pages other then the homepage.

It's a bug in firebase 9 when  You use the firebase experiments:enable webframeworks and next.js
They forgot to add that dependency. The firebase team should solves this issue.